# Print without the excess 0's in a floating point?

Tags: java, floating-point

I understand that you can set the decimal places being printed for a float by doing this `%.2f` but I want to print only significant figures:

```
1.33443
1.3
2.00006
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "significant figures". Can you show an example?

Comment: Let me understand the question. You want to avoid zeros on the right?

Comment: Cast it to a string, remove all trailing chars that are '0' and print it.

Comment: I think 'significant figures' means - 'set a precision to 2 digits' after a floating point.

Comment: The number `2.00006` suggests you are using `float` which is rarely a good idea.  If you use `double` you will get far less rounding error as it has 8 more digits of accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
```

}

Comment: since you are working with floating point, there is no guarantee that the resulting double will still only have 2 significant figures.  and this question is about printing, not rounding.

Comment: k then two.DForm.format(d) would give you the required result

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    float f1 = 1.3344300f;
    float f2 = 1.3000f;
    float f3 = 2.010f;

    System.out.println(f1);;
    System.out.println(f2);;
    System.out.println(f3);;
}
```

Always prints...

```
1.33443
1.3
2.01
```